How to use image files in rkassets programmatically？
There are some image files in RealityKitContent.rkassets. The model will use these files dynamically in the code. For example, add textures to the model. But I found that the image files in rkassets are not found in the code.
ForExample:
File Structure:
- Sources
  |- RealityKitContent
     |- RealityKitContent.swift (this file declares "public let realityKitContentBundle = Bundle.module")
     |- RealityKitContent.rkassets
        |- MyDict1
           |- Textures
              |- A.jpg

The following attempts all failed (all result is not found):
1. TextureResource.init(named: "MyDict1/Textures/A.jpg", in: realityKitContentBundle)
2. TextureResource.init(named: "MyDict1/Textures/A", in: realityKitContentBundle)
3. TextureResource.init(named: "A.jpg", in: realityKitContentBundle)


TextureResource.init(named:in:) is looking for an asset catalog, like Assets.xcassets.
I added an asset catalog to the RK bundle (Xcode named it Media.xcassets), then added an image to the new catalog. After I did that, TextureResource.init(named:in:) worked.
